# Is it possible to cast a Stream in Java 8?

Tags: java, java-8, java-stream

Is it possible to cast a stream in Java 8? Say I have a list of objects, I can do something like this to filter out all the additional objects:

```
Stream.of(objects).filter(c -> c instanceof Client)
```

After this though, if I want to do something with the clients I would need to cast each of them:

```
Stream.of(objects).filter(c -> c instanceof Client)
    .map(c -> ((Client) c).getID()).forEach(System.out::println);
```

This looks a little ugly. Is it possible to cast an entire stream to a different type? Like cast `Stream<Object>` to a `Stream<Client>`?

Please ignore the fact that doing things like this would probably mean bad design. We do stuff like this in my computer science class, so I was looking into the new features of java 8 and was curious if this was possible.

Comment: From the standpoint of the Java runtime the two Stream types are the same already, so no cast is required.  The trick is to sneak it past the compiler.  (That is, assuming it makes any sense to do so.)

Answer (score 388, accepted):

I don't think there is a way to do that out-of-the-box. A possibly cleaner solution would be:

```
Stream.of(objects)
    .filter(c -> c instanceof Client)
    .map(c -> (Client) c)
    .map(Client::getID)
    .forEach(System.out::println);
```

or, as suggested in the comments, you could use the `cast` method - the former may be easier to read though:

```
Stream.of(objects)
    .filter(Client.class::isInstance)
    .map(Client.class::cast)
    .map(Client::getID)
    .forEach(System.out::println);
```

Comment: This is pretty much what I was looking for. I guess I overlooked that casting it to Client in `map` would return a `Stream<Client>`. Thanks!

Comment: +1 interesting new ways, although they risk to get in spaghetti-code of a new-generation type (horizontal, not vertical)

Comment: @LordOfThePigs Yes it works although I am not sure if the code gets clearer. I have added the idea to my answer.

Comment: You could "simplify" the instanceOf filter with:
`Stream.of(objects).filter(Client.class::isInstance).[...]`

Comment: This does not work for untyped Streams. For example `entityManager.createNativeQuery("SQL", Tuple.class).getResultStream().map(Tuple.class::cast).filter(t -> t.get(0) != null)`. It won't compile because it cannot find `.get()`. Even if you expand the parameter type in the lambda it still does not work.

Comment: @T3rm1 when you work with raw types, many things become more difficult...

Answer (score 19):

Along the lines of [ggovan's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/23473558/1237044), I do this as follows:

```
/**
 * Provides various high-order functions.
 */
public final class F {
    /**
     * When the returned {@code Function} is passed as an argument to
     * {@link Stream#flatMap}, the result is a stream of instances of
     * {@code cls}.
     */
    public static <E> Function<Object, Stream<E>> instancesOf(Class<E> cls) {
        return o -> cls.isInstance(o)
                ? Stream.of(cls.cast(o))
                : Stream.empty();
    }
}
```

Using this helper function:

```
Stream.of(objects).flatMap(F.instancesOf(Client.class))
        .map(Client::getId)
        .forEach(System.out::println);
```

Answer (score 13):

Late to the party, but I think it is a useful answer.

`flatMap` would be the shortest way to do it.

```
Stream.of(objects).flatMap(o->(o instanceof Client)?Stream.of((Client)o):Stream.empty())
```

If `o` is a `Client` then create a Stream with a single element, otherwise use the empty stream. These streams will then be flattened into a `Stream<Client>`.

Comment: I tried to implement this, but got a warning saying that my class "uses unchecked or unsafe operations" – is that to be expected?

Comment: unfortunately, yes. Were you to use an `if/else` rather than the `?:` operator then there would be no warning. Rest assured you can safely supress the warning.

Comment: Actually this is longer than `Stream.of(objects).filter(o->o instanceof Client).map(o -> (Client)o)` or even `Stream.of(objects).filter(Client.class::isInstance).map(Client.class::cast)`.

Comment: This gets cleaner with the pattern matching instanceof feature: `Stream.of(objects).flatMap(o -> o instanceof Client c ? Stream.of(c) : Stream.empty())`

Answer (score 8):

> This looks a little ugly. Is it possible to cast an entire stream to a different type? Like cast `Stream<Object>` to a `Stream<Client>`?

No that wouldn't be possible. This is not new in Java 8. This is specific to generics. A `List<Object>` is not a super type of `List<String>`, so you can't just cast a `List<Object>` to a `List<String>`.

Similar is the issue here. You can't cast `Stream<Object>` to `Stream<Client>`. Of course you can cast it indirectly like this:

```
Stream<Client> intStream = (Stream<Client>) (Stream<?>)stream;
```

but that is not safe, and might fail at runtime. The underlying reason for this is, generics in Java are implemented using erasure. So, there is no type information available about which type of `Stream` it is at runtime. Everything is just `Stream`.

BTW, what's wrong with your approach? Looks fine to me.

Comment: It is wrong (read: "ugly") because C# supports this in a very nice fahsion: `enumerable.Cast<MyType>().Where(x => x.SomeMethodOnMyType())`

Comment: @D.R. Generics in `C#` is implemented using reification, while in Java, it is implemented using erasure. Both are implemented in different fashion underlying. So you can't expect it to work same way in both the languages.

Comment: Of course, still, the Java code remains ugly in this case ;-)

Comment: @D.R. I understand that erasure poses many issues for the beginners to understand the concept of generics in Java. And since I don't use C#, I can't go into much detail about comparison. But the whole motivation behind implementing it this way IMO was to avoid major changes in JVM implementation.

Comment: Why would it "certainly fail at runtime"?  As you say there's no (generic) type information, so nothing for the runtime to check.  It might *possibly* fail at runtime, if the wrong types are fed through, but there is no "certainty" about that whatsoever.

Comment: @RohitJain: I'm not criticizing Java's generic concept, but this single consequence still creates ugly code ;-)

Comment: @D.R. - Java generics are ugly from the git-go.  Mostly just C++ feature lust.

Comment: @D.R. @Rohit - the C# `enumerable.Cast` isn't actually "casting the stream".  It is a standard iterator block doing a runtime cast of each element of the stream.  See [here at the .NET reference sources](http://referencesource.microsoft.com/#System.Core/System/Linq/Enumerable.cs,152b93d25e224365).  Java 8 streams could have done this too had they thought to provide it.  (The difference is you'd get the exception for a failed runtime cast at a different point in the code.)  You can't provide it nicely yourself because of the lack of C# extension methods, unfortunately.

Comment: @HotLicks Nonsense. Java Generics and C++ templates have almost nothing in common beyond the notation.

Answer (score 1):

The [`Stream.mapMulti`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/21/docs/api/java.base/java/util/stream/Stream.html#mapMulti(java.util.function.BiConsumer)) method added in Java 16 can be used to cast and keep each element of the given type, skipping and excluding elements not of that type.  In fact, using `mapMulti` in this way to filter and cast the stream is one of the examples shown in the method Javadocs:

> **Examples**
>
> Given a stream of `Number` objects, the following produces a list containing only the `Integer` objects:
>
> ```java
>      Stream<Number> numbers = ... ;
>      List<Integer> integers = numbers.<Integer>mapMulti((number, consumer) -> {
>              if (number instanceof Integer i)
>                  consumer.accept(i);
>          })
>          .collect(Collectors.toList());
> ```

If you're doing a lot of such casting, you could create a resuable `casting` method that accepts the type to be cast to:

```java
private static <T> BiConsumer<Object, Consumer<T>> casting(Class<T> clazz) {
    return (value, mapper) -> {
        if (clazz.isInstance(value)) {
            mapper.accept(clazz.cast(value));
        }
    };
}

// ...

List<Integer> integers = numbers.mapMulti(casting(Integer.class)).toList();
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is a solution using a reusable [`Gatherer`](https://download.java.net/java/early_access/jdk22/docs/api/java.base/java/util/stream/Gatherer.html) per the [JEP 461: Stream Gatherers](https://openjdk.org/jeps/461) Java 22 preview language feature:

```java
Gatherer<Object, Void, Integer> cast =
        Gatherer.of(Integrator.ofGreedy((state, element, downstream) -> {
    if (element instanceof Integer i) {
        return downstream.push(i);
    } else {
        return true;
    }
}));

// Returns [1, 2, 4, 5, 10]
List<Integer> integers = Stream.of(1, 2, 3.0, 4, 5, 6.0, true, 8L, "nine", 10)
        .gather(cast)
        .toList();
```

Or, the same thing but behind a generic method to cast to a requested type:

```java
static <T> Gatherer<Object, ?, T> casting(Class<T> clazz) {
    return Gatherer.of(Integrator.ofGreedy((state, element, downstream) -> {
        if (clazz.isInstance(element)) {
            return downstream.push(clazz.cast(element));
        } else {
            return true;
        }
    }));
}

// ...

// Returns [1, 2, 4, 5, 10]
List<Integer> integers = Stream.of(1, 2, 3.0, 4, 5, 6.0, true, 8L, "nine", 10)
        .gather(casting(Integer.class))
        .toList();
```

This custom gatherer casts and keeps all elements of the given type, and skips any elements that aren't of that type.

## Javadocs

[`Gatherer`](https://download.java.net/java/early_access/jdk22/docs/api/java.base/java/util/stream/Gatherer.html):

> An intermediate operation that transforms a stream of input elements into a stream of output elements, optionally applying a final action when the end of the upstream is reached. […]
>
> […]
>
> There are many examples of gathering operations, including but not limited to: grouping elements into batches (windowing functions); de-duplicating consecutively similar elements; incremental accumulation functions (prefix scan); incremental reordering functions, etc. The class [`Gatherers`](https://download.java.net/java/early_access/jdk22/docs/api/java.base/java/util/stream/Gatherers.html) provides implementations of common gathering operations.
>
> **API Note:**
>
> A `Gatherer` is specified by four functions that work together to process input elements, optionally using intermediate state, and optionally perform a final action at the end of input. They are:
>
> - creating a new, potentially mutable, state ([`initializer()`](https://download.java.net/java/early_access/jdk22/docs/api/java.base/java/util/stream/Gatherer.html#initializer()))
> - integrating a new input element ([`integrator()`](https://download.java.net/java/early_access/jdk22/docs/api/java.base/java/util/stream/Gatherer.html#integrator()))
> - combining two states into one ([`combiner()`](https://download.java.net/java/early_access/jdk22/docs/api/java.base/java/util/stream/Gatherer.html#combiner()))
> - performing an optional final action ([`finisher()`](https://download.java.net/java/early_access/jdk22/docs/api/java.base/java/util/stream/Gatherer.html#finisher()))

[`Stream.gather(Gatherer<? super T,?,R> gatherer)`](https://download.java.net/java/early_access/jdk22/docs/api/java.base/java/util/stream/Stream.html#gather(java.util.stream.Gatherer)):

> Returns a stream consisting of the results of applying the given gatherer to the elements of this stream.

[`Gatherer.of(Gatherer.Integrator<Void,T,R> integrator)`](https://download.java.net/java/early_access/jdk22/docs/api/java.base/java/util/stream/Gatherer.html#of(java.util.stream.Gatherer.Integrator))

> Returns a new, parallelizable, and stateless Gatherer described by the given integrator.

Answer (score -2):

I found when dealing with an untyped collection of one class you can
create a typed collection with

```
UntypedObjCollection bag = some preGenerics method;
List<Foo> foolist = new ArrayList<>();
bag.stream().forEach(o ->fooList.add((Foo)o));
```

There doesn't seem to be a way to cast Object into something and filter, map, etc... in one shot. The only way to get Object into a typed collection is a terminal operation. This is running JDK 17 and dealing with module.base exceptions when trying less granular methods.

Comment: You can do it in a `peek()` too.