# Filter elements from a Java 8 stream that reference a certain subtype with a certain attribute

Tags: java-stream

I have a list of `Car`s where each car has an engine that is defined through the `Engine` interface. In this example concrete types are `CombustionEngine`, with a variable number of cylinders, and `ElectricMotor`.

I want to find all (combustion) engines with four cylinders. Using Java streams I came up with this pipeline:

```java
Car[] carsWithFourCylinders
  = cars.stream()
  .filter( car -> car.engine instanceof CombustionEngine )
  .filter( car -> ( ( CombustionEngine )car.engine ).cylinderCount == 4 )
  .toArray( Car[]::new );
```

While this works, **I was wondering if it is possible to avoid the cast** in the second `filter` predicate or to rewrite the pipeline altogether to be more readable?

---

For reference and in order to experiemnt with I've attached the full source of the example:

```java
public class CarTest {

  interface Engine { }

  class CombustionEngine implements Engine {
    final int cylinderCount;

    CombustionEngine( int cylinderCount ) {
      this.cylinderCount = cylinderCount;
    }
  }

  class ElectricMotor implements Engine { }

  class Car {
    final Engine engine;

    Car( Engine engine ) {
      this.engine = engine;
    }
  }

  @Test
  public void filterCarsWithFourCylinders() {
    List<Car> cars = Arrays.asList( new Car( new CombustionEngine( 4 ) ), 
                                    new Car( new ElectricMotor() ), 
                                    new Car( new CombustionEngine( 6 ) ) );

    Car[] carsWithFourCylinders
      = cars.stream()
      .filter( car -> car.engine instanceof CombustionEngine )
      .filter( car -> ( ( CombustionEngine )car.engine ).cylinderCount == 4 )
      .toArray( Car[]::new );


    assertEquals( 1, carsWithFourCylinders.length );
  }
}
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Is it possible to cast a Stream in Java 8?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22511750/is-it-possible-to-cast-a-stream-in-java-8)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't think it is possible to avoid the cast. After all, neither `Car` nor `Engine` provide any methods which make it possible to differentiate between electric cars and those with an ICE.

But if your `Engine` has no methods, in my opinion it means it should not matter to the `Car` what kind of engine a it has.

The best I could come up with is

```
   final List<Car> combustionCars = cars.stream()
            .collect(groupingBy(c -> c.engine.getClass()))
            .get(CombustionEngine.class);
    long count = combustionCars
            .stream()
            .map(Car::getEngine)
            .map(CombustionEngine.class::cast)
            .filter(c -> c.cylinderCount == 4).collect(Collectors.counting());
```

but I am not sure if this is more readable.