# Converting ArrayList of Objects to an ArrayList of Parent Objects

Tags: java, oop, arraylist

I have files Card.java and Util.java which I am not allowed to modify. For my own purposes, I created a class Card2 which extends Card, and adds an `equals()` method and a `hashcode()` method. The Util class contains a method which takes an `ArrayList<Card>` as a parameter. I have an `ArrayList<Card2>` and I want to run that method.

My understanding is that, in this case, `Card2` has an "is-a" relationship with `Card`, so I would think there should be a way to convert the `ArrayList<Card2>` to `ArrayList<Card>`.

I'm unsure how to go about doing this conversion though. I tried `(ArrayList<Card>) arr` where `arr` is an `ArrayList<Card2>`, but I get an error stating these are inconvertible types. I realize I could create a new `ArrayList<Card>` and add each of the cards in `arr` independently, but I'm wondering whether there's a better way to go about this.

Comment: What I think you should be doing is, from the start, declaring an `ArrayList<Card>` but populating it with `Card2` objects as you create them.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Given a list of Card2:

```
ArrayList<Card2> card2s;
```

Do this:

```
ArrayList<Card> cards = new ArrayList<>(card2s);
```

The constructor accepts a `Collection<? extends Card>`,  which in English is a Collection of anything that is or extends `Card`.

Answer (score 1):

```
    ArrayList<Card2> card2s = new ArrayList<>();

    ArrayList<Card> cards = (ArrayList<Card>)card2s.stream().map(card2 -> {
        Card card = new Card();
        //your logic to take data from card2 variable and set it to the new Card2 object:
        //e.g. card.setType(card2.getType());
        return card;
    }).collect(Collectors.toList());
```

Comment: I'm unsure how this converts an ArrayList<Card2> arr to ArrayList<Card>

Comment: It creates a stream of cards, and then maps each object of type `Card` to the new object of type `Card2`. You have to set the data or whatever you wish in each object in the commented area, and then it returns mapped object. Finally it collects it into collection.

Comment: Yeah, I commented before you made the edit. I'm currently testing it in my code.

Comment: Excuse me? before who made the edit? :) this is just a concept of how to convert one list into another. `cards2` is just an example data.

Comment: Damn, I'm sorry :') For some reason I thought someone else had commented explaining your answer.

Comment: Only thing I had to change is casting the result to an `ArrayList<Card>` from `List<Card>`. Other than that, it works! Thanks! If you can edit your answer so it includes that casting, then I can accept your answer.

Comment: Done; however, it's much better to hold your variables type more generic like `List`, than specialized like `ArrayList`.

Comment: Damn, just saw @Bohemian 's response, and it's much more elegant. Thanks for helping with your answer though!

Comment: It's elegant; however, it will only work if you have an inheritance in the place. With my answer you can convert any object to any other type.

Comment: Hm yeah. My question was asking specifically about scenarios where inheritance is used, but yeah, I can see this being useful in other contexts.

Answer (score 1):

If you have access to that util method, you can use wildcard character in input parameters as described...

https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/extra/generics/wildcards.html

"There is a small but very important difference here: we have replaced the type List with List<? extends Shape>. Now drawAll() will accept lists of any subclass of Shape, so we can now call it on a List if we want"

If you don't have access to that method you can still cast items inside the list. Sample by Java stream api:

[Is it possible to cast a Stream in Java 8?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22511750/is-it-possible-to-cast-a-stream-in-java-8)