# Cast call in map stream operation not working

Tags: java, java-stream

I have the following (using org.json.simple):

```
 import org.json.simple.JSONArray;
 import org.json.simple.JSONObject;
 ...
 final JSONArray results = (JSONArray) responseObject.get("results");
 results
        .stream()
        .filter(JSONObject.class::isInstance)
        .map(JSONObject.class::cast)
        .map(obj -> obj) // obj is still Object here, not JSONObject?
```

The problem is that after I call map to cast the stream elements to `JSONObject`, on the next call to map, the elements are still `Object`, not `JSONObject`. Not sure what I'm doing wrong here?

Related: [Is it possible to cast a Stream in Java 8?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22511750/is-it-possible-to-cast-a-stream-in-java-8)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

[org.json.simple.JSONArray](http://miamarti.github.io/HorusFramework/javadoc/org/json/simple/JSONArray.html) extends `java.util.ArrayList`, which means it extends a raw type.

As a result, `results.stream()` returns a raw `Stream` instead of a `Stream<SomeElementType>`, and even after the calls to `map()`, you still get a raw `Stream`, so the casting doesn't help you.

If `org.json.simple.JSONArray` extended `ArrayList<Object>` instead, you would have gotten a `Stream<Object>`, and after the call to `.map(JSONObject.class::cast)`, a `Stream<JSONObject>`.

I believe you should be able to get over that with the following unchecked cast:

```
final JSONArray results = (JSONArray) responseObject.get("results");
List<Object> genericResults = (List<Object>) results;
List<JSONObject> list =
    genericResults.stream()
                  .filter(JSONObject.class::isInstance)
                  .map(JSONObject.class::cast)
                  .collect(Collectors.toList());
```